# Extraction of events from requirements stated in English

Tags: nlp

The input to my Java program is a simple text file which contains requirements expressed in natural language English. 
My program should be able to extract events from the requirements. 
It should also be able to identify sequence of events or relationship among events in terms of causative and/or trigger events.

I have already tried Stanford NLP but got no solution.

Comment: This is a hard problem that could be solved in a lot of ways. What in CoreNLP did you try?

Comment: Try to use opennlp, it's quite promising